# node.js display virtual hosts and current git branch async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, shell

Ok, i am just starting to learn node.js and i am having a little difficulty getting a good grasp on the async nature of it and when/how to use callbacks to get data passed along like i need it.

The concept of what i am trying to build is this.  I have a small node.js app that uses the FS package - defined as `var fs = require("fs")`.  The app is responding to localhost:4000 right now.  When i hit that url, the app will use `fs.readdir()` to get all of the virtual host files in the directory that i pass to `readdir()`.

Next, the app loops through those files and parses each one line by line and word by word (quick and dirty for now).  I am using `fs.readFile()` to read the file and then literally doing `lines = data.toString().split("\n")` and then `var words = lines[l].split(" ")` to get to the data in the file i need.  Each virtual host file looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName some-site.local
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/the/docroot"
    <Directory "/path/to/the/docroot">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/some-site.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my main.js file (routes file):

```
var express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router(),
    async = require("async"),
    directoryReader = require(__dirname + "/../lib/directoryReader");
    fileReader = require(__dirname + "/../lib/fileReader");

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    var response = [];

    directoryReader.read(function(files) {
        async.each(files, function(file, callback) {
            fileReader.read(file, function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    response.push(data);
                }

                callback();
            });
        }, function(err){
            if (err) throw err;

            res.json(response);
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My directoryReader.js file:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    fileReader = require(__dirname + "/../lib/fileReader");

var directoryReader = {
    read: function(callback) {
        var self = this;

        fs.readdir("/etc/apache2/sites-available", function (err, files) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var output = [];
            for(f in files) {
                output.push(files[f]);
            }
            callback(output);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = directoryReader;
```

And my fileReader.js file:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var fileReader = {
    read: function(file, callback) {
        fs.readFile("/etc/apache2/sites-available/" + file, { encoding: "utf8" }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var vHostStats = ["servername", "documentroot", "errorlog"],
                lines = data.toString().split("\n"),
                output = [];

            for(l in lines) {
                var words = lines[l].split(" ");

                for(w in words) {
                    if (words[w].toLowerCase() == "<virtualhost") {
                        var site = {
                            "servername" : "",
                            "documentroot" : "",
                            "errorlog" : "",
                            "gitbranch" : ""
                        }
                        w++;
                    }

                    if (vHostStats.indexOf(words[w].toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                        var key = words[w].toLowerCase();

                        w++;
                        site[key] = words[w];
                    }

                    if (words[w].toLowerCase() == "</virtualhost>" && site.documentroot != "") {
                        w++;
                        output.push(site);

                        var cmd = "cd " + site["documentroot"] + " && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD";
                        var branch = ...; // get Git branch based on the above command

                        site["gitbranch"] = branch;
                    }
                }
            }
            callback(output);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = fileReader;
```

All of this code will spit out json.  This all works fine, expect for one part.  The line in the `fileReader.js` file:

```
var branch = ...; // get Git branch based on the above command
```

I am trying to get this code to run a shell command and get the Git branch based on the document root directory.  I then want to take the branch returned and add the value to the `gitbranch` proptery of the current `site` object during the loop.  Hope this makes sense.  I know there are probably questions on SO that cover something similar to this and i have looked at many of them.  I fear i am just not educated enough in node.js yet to apply the answers to those SO questions to my particular use case.

Please let me know if there's anything i can add that can help anyoe answer this question.  I should note that this app is for personal uses only, so the solution really just has to work, not be super elegant.

**UPDATE: (5/1/2015)**

Probably not the best solution but i got what i wanted by using the new `execSync` added to v0.12.x

```
if (words[w].toLowerCase() == "</virtualhost>" && site.documentroot != "") {
    var cmd = "cd " + site["documentroot"] + " && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD";
    var branch = sh(cmd, { encoding: "utf8" });

    site["gitbranch"] = branch.toString().trim();

    w++;
    output.push(site);
}
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using? if 0.12.x there is child_process.execSync that you may want to use: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options. Otherwise you can use child_process.exec and set the branch in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that.  Right now i'm on v0.10.x but may update it to 0.12.x.  Will i be able to use `site["gitbranch"] = branch` in the callback?  Still learning node's flow of things and i'm not sure if that will work or if the current site object would possibly not be the same one it was on when the git command was called.  I had tried `child_process.exec` and logged inside of it and the logs didn't fire until the very end so i want to make sure i can stick the branch name with the correct site object. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was able to get it to work with `execSync`.